# Instead of russian data I see data on English

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have russian website and instead of russian data I see data on English.

```
   <?php 
    $dbc_utf8 = mysqli_connect ("mysite.com", "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
    mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, 'SET CHARACTER utf8');
    mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
             /*  Installing Russian locale Connection */
             mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, "SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU'") ;    
    ?>
```

I have database where I need field "date_add" on Russian. On screen I see "23 February 2014"

```
CREATE TABLE `comment_common` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_post` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_shop` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11568 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=11568 ;
```

**In database**

```
$sql = "
        SELECT id, parent_id, name, comment,
        DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%d %M %Y') as date_add
        FROM comment_common
";
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: what is your server operation system?

Answer (score 0):

Get the time from database, and put that on variable. Then try this code:

If you are running Linux on the server use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
echo strftime(); //PS down
```

you can learn how to use this function from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

If you are using Windows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'russian');
```

Comment: I use <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

You should run those queries putting them in one SQL run

```
$sql = "
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU'; 
SELECT id, parent_id, name, comment,
        DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%d %M %Y') as date_add
        FROM comment_common;";
```

If I run it this way in phpMyAdmin I had displayed it in correct language: `14 Сентября 2014` but when I first run first query, and then the second query I also had data in English.

To get desired result you should use `mysqli_store_result()` function so the correct code for that would be:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$dbc_utf8 = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "tests");
mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, 'SET CHARACTER utf8');
mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, 'SET NAMES utf8');
/*  Installing Russian locale Connection */
$sql = "
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
 SELECT id, parent_id, name, comment,
        DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%d %M %Y') as date_add
        FROM comment_common
";

if (mysqli_multi_query($dbc_utf8, $sql)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($dbc_utf8)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['date_add'];
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }

    } while (mysqli_more_results($dbc_utf8) && mysqli_next_result($dbc_utf8));
}
?>
```

However it is not very convenient. It seems that instead of `SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU'` you should use `SET GLOBAL lc_time_names = 'ru_RU'` to make it work in normal code so the better option should be:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$dbc_utf8 = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "tests");
mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, 'SET CHARACTER utf8');
mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, 'SET NAMES utf8');
/*  Installing Russian locale Connection */
mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, "SET GLOBAL lc_time_names = 'ru_RU'") ;

$sql = "
        SELECT id, parent_id, name, comment,
        DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%d %M %Y') as date_add
        FROM comment_common
";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc_utf8, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['date_add'];



?>
```

However in this case you need admin privileges and I don't know why but this code doesn't work in first run, from 2nd it returns date in Russian language.

Comment: in this case I have "Error querying database".